# Solve Call to a member function combinestring() on a non-object

Tags: php, class

I met a problem when Call to a member function combinestring() on a non-object.

```
**Index.php**
inlcude("string.php");
calldata('usa');


**string.php**
$a=new a();
funciton calldata($val){
$st1="select a from table 1 where country=".$a->combinestring($val);
return $st1;
}

**Class A**
function combinestring($abc){
   Return "'".$abc."'";
}
```

Unknow $a->combinestring($val);

How to solve this problem.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting error

> Call to a member function combinestring() on a non-object

because you are calling a member function on the variable that is not an object. That means `$a` is not an object.

In string.php , you cannot use `$a` inside function definition because variable has local scope. You cannot access that object instance like that. You can however do this by using global variable.

Your `string.php` file should be like this:

```
$a=new a();
funciton calldata($val){
   global $a;
   $st1="select a from table 1 where country=".$a->combinestring($val);
   return $st1;
}
```

Head to this link for more information on variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `PDO`.

```
funciton calldata($val){
   $st1="select a from table 1 where country = ?";
   $pdo = new PDO('host', 'user', 'pass');
   $result = $pdo->prepare($st1)->execute($val);
   return $result;
}
```

This is a lot different from what you are doing, but your `a` class does not escape the input to the query and that's bad.